# Assign outbound E-mail to specific Ironport server

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I'm not a Cisco ASA engineer but wanted to ask if it is possible to create a custom rule to filter a specific outbound email address, like ironportcheck1@contso.com, and assign it to  pass thru a specific member of Ironport servers, like for instance Ironport server4762, every single time that email is used to send outbound email. Thanks much

Comment: I think you need a NextGen firewall that can do Deep Packet Inspection to peer into the application data.

Comment: SMTP routing requires an SMTP server. The point at which any email address is exchanged is deep into the conversation.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the ASA will do that level of protocol filtering and rewriting for you. If I needed to accomplish that I would instead probably put another SMTP server in the path that mail needed to flow through before getting to the firewall and use rules in the SMTP server to redirect email as needed. You could then use a firewall to block all outgoing SMTP traffic except from the rule enforcing SMTP server.